# EF 6 Fluent API with One to Many AND Many To Many and conflicting multiplicities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific problem, perhaps to my newness with Entity Framework

I have two Entities: User and Facility.

The Facility table requires an Owner (user), but a Facility can also have many "FacilityUsers" assigned to a Facility.

```
public class User
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
}

public Facility Facility
{
    public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> FacilityUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my ModelBuilder

```
////Many To Many: Users To Facilities
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Facilities)
    .WithMany(u => u.FacilityUsers)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        m.MapRightKey("FacilityId");
        m.ToTable("UserFacility");
    });        

//One to Many: Facility To Owner
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
    .HasRequired<User>(s => s.Owner)
    .WithMany(s => s.Facilities)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId);
```

The problem is, when I have the map **Facility to Owner**, I get the following error: **The navigation property 'FacilityUsers' declared on type 'MEH.Web.Models.Entities.Facility' has been configured with conflicting multiplicities**.

However, when I exclude the **Facility to Owner** mapping, it works.

```
//One to Many: Facility To Owner
//modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
//    .HasRequired<User>(s => s.Owner)
//    .WithMany(s => s.Facilities)
//    .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId);
```

The problem is, the **Facilities** table then has a **Owner_UserId** field that is null, but the **OwnerId** is correctly filled in.  My OCD won't let me move on until I have resolved the "Owner_UserId" problem.

Thank you,
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't map *one* collection navigation property (`Facilities`) to *two* relationships.

Either add another collection for `one-to-many` relationship:

```
public class User
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Facility> OwnedFacilities { get; set; }
}
```

and map it:

```
//One to Many: Facility To Owner
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Owner)
    .WithMany(s => s.OwnedFacilities) // <- another collection
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId);
```

or keep the `User` model as it is now, but configure `one-to-many` relationship as *unidirectional* (without collection navigation property):

```
//One to Many: Facility To Owner
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
    .HasRequired(s => s.Owner)
    .WithMany() // <- no collection
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.OwnerId);
```